# PrependTo function is not working efficiently?

Tags: jquery

I am using `prependTo()` to move `extract_me` class and add it to `addme_here` class for small to medium size devices.

`extract_me` class exist of 1 row and 2 columns, while 1 column of 1st row further divided into two section which stay together. `product_content` class has background and containing all the elements of 1 row. but for smaller devices 2 column of 1 rows jump outside the `product_content` and add inside `addme_here`. it is working correctly but it is responding bit slow. anyone can see it is moving, it's not looking like that section is already there.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    location.reload();
  });
  if ($(document).width() < 992) {
    console.log("i am medium size device ");
    if ($(document).find('.extract_me')) {
      $(".extract_me").prependTo($(".addme_Here"));
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.product-content {
  background: url(https://www.freepptbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Light-Blue-Effect-PPT-Backgrounds.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  padding: 40px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-content mb-3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-9 mb-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2 slider">
            <h1>hello</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
              book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
              recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- RIGHT SIDE -->
      <div class="extract_me col-sm-12 col-lg-3 ">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col">
            <h1 class="thick_text" id="top">Digital Albums</h1>
            <p>Prices from <span style="font-size:25px">£0.11p</span></p>
            <p>hfuytg bjb bkjb bvgkujb byu</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
              book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
              recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container addme_Here">
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-lg">
      <p> please add here </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: resize fires multiple times so you keep adding the same thing....

Comment: @epascarello I've formatted the code so it's more readable. They're only refreshing the page on resize - which in itself is very weird, and will cause other problems.

Comment: `$(window).resize(function() {
    location.reload();
  });` is a bad idea..... why are you not just using CSS Media queries.

Comment: `if ($(document).find('.extract_me')) {` is always truthy.  Objects are truthy.  You need to check the `.length`

Comment: @epascarello, i add that line only for some testing reason. i can remove it any time. i am not worried about that. as you suggested to use media query, i can do that and my 2 column will go down for small devices. i know for that i don't need to write any js only col-sm-12 will work. but this column is inside a container and that container is inside a class product_content. that class is using background property. i want that background only for 1 column not in 2 column for 2 column.